# Same maze with same seed c++

Tags: c++, maze, seeding

I have coded a random maze generator and it totally works. However I want to make it so that if the user types in the same seed (third command line parameter) it generates the same maze. I was wondering what the best way to do that is, should I output stream the maze and the seed into a separate file. When a seed is called compare the 2 seeds and if they are the same, call the corresponding maze in the file. Or how would you guys suggest I do it?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is the code that uses my randomizer

```
    std::mt19937 rng(std::random_device{}());
    Grid[yPos][xPos] = " ";
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> Directions{{
        {North, 0},
        {South, 0},
        {0, East},
        {0, West},
    }};
    // Shuffle vector
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int j = i + rng() % (4 - i);
        std::swap(Directions[i], Directions[j]);
    }
    // Loop over a range of directions
    for(std::pair<int, int>& pair : Directions) {
        int toY = pair.first;
        int toX = pair.second;
        int y2 = yPos + toY * 2;
        int x2 = xPos + toX * 2;
        if(checkValid(y2, x2) && Grid[y2][x2] == "#") {
            Grid[yPos + toY][xPos + toX] = " ";
            carvePath(y2, x2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are probably already using a seed in some way. just don't invent a new one - how are you currently generating your "random" maze?

Comment: You should provide how you are doing the random part currently.  Most random number generators take seed values to start.  Providing the same seed will provide same list of random numbers.

Comment: Could you show some code? What random generator are you using? Without that, difficult to answer. (you can edit your question and insert sample code)

Comment: I'm assuming youre using some kind of PRNG to create the maze randomly, and that you seed that PRNG some way? If you seed the PRNG with the same seed it should generate the same sequence, which should give you the same maze.

Comment: You seem to have a wrong understanding of what a "seed" is. There is no need to save a maze, in order to be able to load that same maze again whenever the user enters the same seed. Instead, whenever you seed the same pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) with the same seed, then you should always get the exact same sequence of random numbers, which means that you should always get the exact same maze.

Comment: So instead of passing `std::random_device{}()` to the constructor of `rng` you should be passing in the user provided seed (if the user did provide one). That should be sufficient for your scenario

Comment: Your seed is currently `std::random_device{}()`.

Comment: offtopic: see [std::uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

Comment: It works, however when I dont input a seed now, I dont really get a maze anymore, it's just a simple line

Comment: `std::mt19937 rng(std::random_device{}());` followed by `Grid[yPos][xPos] = " ";` is very suspicious. It implies to me that you may be initializing a random number generator for each cell. This is inefficient, will likely reduce the quality of the distribution and will make it very hard to use an initial seed. You should initialize the random number generator once at the start of the generation process, at which point you can easily pass it whatever seed you want.

Comment: So outside the function? @François Andrieux

Comment: @Jojo The code shown is incomplete, and I don't really understand the logic behind the code shown (the comments are not very helpful, they don't express intend or the objective of the commented code) so it's hard to say where or how you should do this.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to store anything.

`std::mt19937` is a *pseudo*-random number generator.  You provide a seed when you construct it, and the seed completely determines the sequence of random numbers that it generates.

You should just hash your user-entered seed and pass the hash to this constructor instead of using `random_device`.

Then the user-entered seed will completely determine which maze you get.

You can see an example of seeding this generated from a string here: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mersenne_twister_engine/mersenne_twister_engine/

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "pass the hash to the contructor"

Comment: For better or worse for you, exactly what they said. None of the language used in the answer should be foreign to a C++ dev, or any OOP dev for that matter. Replace `std::random_device` with the user-provided seed. Hashing it is optional, but recommended.

Comment: @Jojo what do you mean by "I have coded a random maze generator"?